How long before my Kryptex gets updated?
I just registered and started to mine with a Xeon(R) Gold 6148 using all cores (roughly 130Ghz). How long until the Number of computers: 0 will be updated and how long until the 0.00000000 BTC balance goes up to 0.00000001 BTC with this kind of hardware?
I'm not sure if I'm allowed post what command I'm running. Maybe without my wallet name? I just want to make sure it's the correct way of running it.
The worker is doing 17000 H/s so it's not the greatest for mining I suppose.

Even a decade-old single-core CPU can do a few Mhash/s; 17000 hash/s seems wildly off if you were actually mining bitcoin. In either case, you simply cannot mine bitcoin with just a CPU and expect any income at all, you need specialized ASIC hardware these days. I have never heard about them, but consider the possibility that Kryptex might be a scam, as many mining services are.

Thanks yeah seems off. Can you suggest a known and valid and legit service i should use? Thanks

Without specialized ASIC mining hardware, you - unfortunately - should not be mining BTC at all. It's always going to be a losing effort.


how long until the 0.00000000 BTC balance goes up to 0.00000001 BTC with this kind of hardware?

Never. At 17000 H/s and current network difficulty.
See

In the ASIC-age, is it worth starting mining Bitcoin at home?
Is the native Bitcoin client intended for mining?

